# Ionic emulate ios only works with --livereload

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I have a simple ionic app that I'm building and when I test with `ionic serve --lab`, everything looks great, however, when I try to emulate on the simulators with `ionic emulate ios` or `ionic emulate android`, the app doesn't load (seems like all the JS isn't coming through). I am able to attach the debugger and there aren't any console errors.

But, when I do try and run the app with `ionic emulate ios --livereload` everything seems to work fine.

I tried another sample app from scratch to rule out my machine env and it worked fine.

Any ideas on how I can get the emulate to work without --livereload?

Comment: I am having the same issue with you , but seems no one has any experience on this issue

Comment: My first check is always to ````ionic platform remove ios```` and ````ionic platform add ios````. Tried?

Comment: did you try to build before you emulate?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, works in the browser fine without live reload, when I try it in the emulator, just a whitescreen but i can add text to the file it's loading... seems like a JS error but nothing in the logs

Comment: already solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. I resolved it by removing certain angular dependencies that weren't being detected by the ios build. Check your jslint for any warnings that may provide more information about which dependencies may be injected incorrectly or missing.

See [this comment](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/showing-blank-white-screen/15545/16) on the Ionic forums for further info.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the white screen of death was caused by bad references to bower components.

For our build process, the relative location of bower components is different is the "source" compared to when the app has been packaged to "www" (bower components are copied to the root directory).

The following reference works when the app is served (if you hover over the links in Chrome inspector, the ".." is removed), but don't work when launched on a device/emulator:

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Live reload works because the **application is not being served from the device's file system**.  Instead Ionic is serving it from the host machine and presumably the bad relative path ("..") is silently ignored as it is when tested in the browser.

Fixing the paths as follows resolved in the problem:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

The outstanding question is why no apparent errors are thrown by any component of the application.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Find Errors

Start your emulation like this

```
 $ ionic emulate android -l -c
```

This will emulate with livereload and **log to your console**.

Now you should see whats causing the error, logged in the terminal.

#### 2. Missing Cordova Whitelist Plugin?

Often there's the missing **Cordova Whitelist Plugin**. As you can read [here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist) simply do the following steps to get this plugn to work.

```
$ ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

if not already added.

open your `config.xml` inside your project root and add this line inside the `<widget>` tag.

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by having a `<base href="/">` in my index.html, which did not prevent Ionic from finding locally hosted files (via --livereload), but totally prevented Ionic from finding files inside of bundled iOS or Android apps.